# Why is length not considered a method in this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def longest_word(string)
  words = string.split
  idx = 0
  while idx < words.length
    if words[idx].length > words[idx + 1].length
      longest = words[idx]
    else
      longest = words [idx + 1]
    end
    idx += 1
  end
  return longest
end

puts(longest_word("peas rambling tattoo") == "rambling")
```

keep getting error message

longest_word.rb:5:in `longest_word': undefined method`length' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from longest_word.rb:15:in `'

any information on why this is happening would be great

Comment: while idx < words.length -1 works for u.

Answer (score 6):

`words.length` returns the number of elements, but the index starts with 0.

You need a `(words.length - 1)`

```
def longest_word(string)
  words = string.split
  idx = 0
  while idx < (words.length - 1)
    if words[idx].length > words[idx + 1].length
      longest = words[idx]
    else
      longest = words [idx + 1]
    end
    idx += 1
  end
  return longest
end

puts(longest_word("peas rambling tattoo") == "rambling")
```

Your code is not 'rubyesk', I would prefer:

```
def longest_word(string)
  longest = ''
  string.split.each do |word|
    longest = word.length > longest.length ? word : longest
  end
  return longest
end

puts(longest_word("peas rambling tattoo") == "rambling")
```

or maybe better:

```
def longest_word(string)
  longest = ''
  string.split.each do |word|
      longest = word  if word.length > longest.length 
  end
  return longest
end

puts(longest_word("peas rambling tattoo") == "rambling")
```

You can also use `max_by` to get shorter code:

```
def longest_word(string)
  string.split.max_by{|word| word.length}
end

puts(longest_word("peas rambling tattoo") == "rambling")
```

Or even shorter with `string.split.max_by(&:length)`